# Negate match in RE2 syntax?

Tags: regex, re2

How can I write a regex in RE2 for "match strings not starting with 4 or 5"?

In PCRE I'd use `^(?!4)` but RE2 [doesn't support that syntax](https://code.google.com/p/re2/wiki/Syntax).

Comment: You can use `^[^45]` but it will consume a character.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^[^45]
```

`^` matches start and `[^45]` matches anything but `4` or `5` at start.

Comment: And if you also want to match the empty string, use `^(?:[^45]|$)`.

Comment: Yes that's right, thanks for adding this important addendum @TimPietzcker

Comment: similar to this how to omit the word when it contains `-ed` in it? any idea for this [link](https://regex101.com/r/I5Wsbf/3). Here 2 match cases are working fine, but condition on negate (not matching case) seems to be not working. Pls correct me if i'm wrong. @anubhava

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variant of the solution for strings of words, not individual characters.

The way I do it is to look twice.

First, find all the items that match, then filter them to get the final answer

### example

- test data

  ```
  aaabaraaa
  aaafooaaa
  aaazooaaa
  aaaqooaaa
  ```

  suppose I want to find center text(between "aaa"), and it should not be "bar" or "foo"

it's easy with PCRE<sup>1</sup> => https://regex101.com/r/nJcbt1/1/

use re2 I will choose divide and conquer: To a reduced scope with the group, and then filter.

a solution writing with Golang => [image: Go Playground]

---

<sup>[1]</sup> PCRE: [Perl Compatible Regular Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions)